# Azure Rest API Delete Message from Queue returning 403 (working ok in others method)

Tags: api, rest, azure, queue, storage

I just code 4 methods for API REST, but the last I need is not working. This is deleting the message queue. I have this code:

```
public static string DeleteMessage(String queueName, string account, byte[] key, string endpoint, string popreceipt,string messageid)
    {
        string requestMethod = "DELETE";

        String urlPath = String.Format("{0}/messages/{1}?popreceipt={2}", queueName,Uri.EscapeDataString(messageid),Uri.EscapeDataString(popreceipt));

        String storageServiceVersion = "2009-09-19";
        String dateInRfc1123Format = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        String canonicalizedHeaders = String.Format(
              "x-ms-date:{0}\nx-ms-version:{1}",
              dateInRfc1123Format,
              storageServiceVersion);
        String canonicalizedResource = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", account, urlPath);
        //String canonicalizedResource = String.Format("/{0}/{1}\npopreceipt:{2}", account, urlPath, popreceipt);
        String stringToSign = String.Format(
              "{0}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{1}\n{2}",
              requestMethod,
              canonicalizedHeaders,
              canonicalizedResource);
        String authorizationHeader = CreateAuthorizationHeader(stringToSign, account, key);

        Uri uri = new Uri(endpoint + urlPath);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = requestMethod;
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", dateInRfc1123Format);
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", storageServiceVersion);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            return response.StatusCode.ToString();

        }
    }

    public static string GetMessage(String queueName,string account, byte[] key,string endpoint)
    {
        string requestMethod = "GET";

        String urlPath = String.Format("{0}/messages", queueName);

        String storageServiceVersion = "2009-09-19";
        String dateInRfc1123Format = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        String canonicalizedHeaders = String.Format(
              "x-ms-date:{0}\nx-ms-version:{1}",
              dateInRfc1123Format,
              storageServiceVersion );
        String canonicalizedResource = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", account, urlPath);
        String stringToSign = String.Format(
              "{0}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{1}\n{2}",
              requestMethod,
              canonicalizedHeaders,
              canonicalizedResource);
        String authorizationHeader = CreateAuthorizationHeader(stringToSign,account,key);

        Uri uri = new Uri(endpoint + urlPath);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = requestMethod;
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", dateInRfc1123Format);
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", storageServiceVersion );
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
        request.Accept = "application/atom+xml,application/xml";

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
            {
                String responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

                return responseFromServer;
            }
        }
    }
```

GetMessage is just working and DeleteMessage is not working, the CreateAuthorithation Headers Code is :

```
     private static String CreateAuthorizationHeader(String canonicalizedString, string account, byte[] key)
    {
        String signature = string.Empty;
        using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(key))
        {
            Byte[] dataToHmac = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(canonicalizedString);
            signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
        }

        String authorizationHeader = String.Format(
              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
              "{0} {1}:{2}",
              "SharedKey",
              account,
              signature);

        return authorizationHeader;
    }
```

I pass the KEY using "Convert.FromBase64String(AccountSharedKey)", that works for GetMessage (and also another method for put message), but this is not working for DELETING THE MESSAGE.

I see the API in MSDN and DELETE and GET message use the same parameters, except the parameters passed by the query string.

SOLVED

The problem was that I din´t use UriEscape for the parameters in the Uri string, and sometimes the URL was valid and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there's an issue with the way you're constructing "canonicalizedResource" string. Based on the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx (scroll down to the section titled "Constructing the Canonicalized Resource String"), you should not be passing the Query String parameters as part of the main canonicalized resource string. They should be appended separately.

Can you see if using the following works:

```
            string canonicalizedResource = string.Format("/{0}/{1}/messages/{2}\npopreceipt:{3}", account, queueName, messageid, popreceipt);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I Finally read that. I know that the problem is in the canonicalized Resource, but if the request is: http://myaccount.queue.core.windows.net/myqueue/messages/messageid?popreceipt=string-value, I think that the string may be: string canonicalizedResource string.Format("/{0}/{1}/messages/messageid\npopreceipt:{2}", account, queueName, popreceipt); What do you think? Still not working!!!

Comment: You're correct. I forgot to include queue name above. I have corrected it.

Comment: Hi, I try what you said finally, using "messageid" as the parameter that i send in the query string, and also without the parameter, using the string "messageid". This is still not working. Could I send you a console project and you test it yourself? GetMessage working and DeleteMessage not working... Here is the project if you want to test it: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/38063432/C%23.zip

Comment: I ran your program and it worked perfectly fine for me without making any changes to your code. What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: Man, this is really crazy... I only change the StorageAccount with a new one... I gonna kill myself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code and it worked fine for me. I created a queue, inserted a message did a "GET" message on that to get the pop receipt and then deleted the message. Only thing I modified in your code is the canonicalizedResource string based on my answer above:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication15
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string messageId = "<message id e.g. ba9bdbe6-cd10-465d-ab32-90756ea0471d>";
            string queueName = "<queue name e.g. abc>";
            string accountName = "<your account name>";
            string accountKey = "<you account key base64 encoded string>";
            string endpoint = "http://accountname.queue.core.windows.net/";
            string popreceipt = "<pop receipt e.g. AgAAAAEAAAAAAAAACuMLtGTIzQE=>";

            var result = DeleteMessage(queueName, accountName, Convert.FromBase64String(accountKey), endpoint,
                popreceipt, messageId);
        }

        public static string DeleteMessage(String queueName, string account, byte[] key, string endpoint, string popreceipt, string messageid)
        {
            string requestMethod = "DELETE";

            String urlPath = String.Format("{0}/messages/{1}?popreceipt={2}", queueName, Uri.EscapeDataString(messageid), Uri.EscapeDataString(popreceipt));

            String storageServiceVersion = "2009-09-19";
            String dateInRfc1123Format = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            String canonicalizedHeaders = String.Format(
                  "x-ms-date:{0}\nx-ms-version:{1}",
                  dateInRfc1123Format,
                  storageServiceVersion);
            String canonicalizedResource = string.Format("/{0}/{1}/messages/{2}\npopreceipt:{3}", account, queueName, messageid, popreceipt);
            String stringToSign = String.Format(
                  "{0}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{1}\n{2}",
                  requestMethod,
                  canonicalizedHeaders,
                  canonicalizedResource);
            String authorizationHeader = CreateAuthorizationHeader(stringToSign, account, key);

            Uri uri = new Uri(endpoint + urlPath);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = requestMethod;
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", dateInRfc1123Format);
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", storageServiceVersion);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                return response.StatusCode.ToString();

            }
        }

        private static String CreateAuthorizationHeader(String canonicalizedString, string account, byte[] key)
        {
            String signature = string.Empty;
            using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(key))
            {
                Byte[] dataToHmac = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(canonicalizedString);
                signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
            }

            String authorizationHeader = String.Format(
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                  "{0} {1}:{2}",
                  "SharedKey",
                  account,
                  signature);

            return authorizationHeader;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very old thread but I bumped into the same problem. I'm unable to DELETE a message in the queue through REST API.I've used your sample code and it throws an error like `The remote server returned an error: (403) Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature..`

Comment: I believe the error you're getting is because the account name needs to come twice in case of storage emulator. So if you change the following line `String canonicalizedResource = string.Format("/{0}/{1}/messages/{2}\npopreceipt:{3}", account, queueName, messageid, popreceipt);` to `String canonicalizedResource = string.Format("/{0}/{0}/{1}/messages/{2}\npopreceipt:{3}", account, queueName, messageid, popreceipt);`, I think you should not get this error.

Comment: Still the same issue in DEV storage emulator. I tried even changing the queue to point to AzureStorage instead of DEV storage. Still the same error.

Comment: Please post a new question with complete code you’re using.